# I want to Store Date specific to "Arabian Standard Time" irrespective of the time zone on web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-4.0

I have been trying to find ways to save Datetime specific to "Arabian Standard Time" which is +4 UTC.
So far I have not been successful.
Here's an example:

```
Response.Write("<br>System Time : " + DateTime.Now);
timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Arabian Standard Time");

dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timeZoneInfo);
Response.Write("<br>Arabian Standard Time : " + dateTime);
```

It always gives me the same datetime zone which I set on the desktop.

Can I set the time zone in web.config so that I will have datetime specific to a country on the application level?

Comment: I managed to get it right after using following code....
        TimeZoneInfo UAETimeZone =    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Arabian Standard Time");
        DateTime utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime UAE = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, UAETimeZone);
        Response.Write("<brUTC : " + utc);
        Response.Write("<br>Arabian Standard Time UAE : " + UAE);

Comment: Don't paste code in comments.  Post your code as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it right after using following code..

```
TimeZoneInfo UAETimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Arabian Standard Time");  DateTime utc = DateTime.UtcNow; 
DateTime UAE = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, UAETimeZone); 
Response.Write("<brUTC : " + utc); 
Response.Write("<br>Arabian Standard Time UAE : " + UAE);
```

Now even if i change my desktop timezone it will always give me the time zone of "Arabian Standard Time"

Comment: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391%28v=winembedded.11%29.aspx) is `Time Zone Index Values` from `msdn`, may help someone.